# C# unsigned int 96-bit

Tags: c#, class, int, unsigned

Can you help me implement a class that represents an 96-bit unsigned int?

I've called this class Flag96.

Code:

```
class Flag96
{
    private object array = new uint[3];

    public Flag96(uint a1, uint a2, uint a3)
    {
        uint[] _array = (uint[])array;

        _array[0] = a1;
        _array[2] = a2;
        _array[3] = a3;
    }
}
```

But when I try to use it with:

```
public Flag96[] example;
```

It will not work. The maximum integer size defined by Microsoft is 64-bit, so I need a new class.

Comment: What is the rationale behind needing a 96-bit number?

Comment: What do you want this class to do? What problem are you experiencing while trying to get it to do what you want?

Comment: [Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx). You 're welcome.

Comment: Probably just a typo, but [2], [3] should be [1], [2]. And why declare array as object?

Comment: What exactly is it that "will not work"? Your class seems to hold three `UInt32`, and that's a total of 96 bits. That's a start, and you can fix the problems mentioned by Henrik and Tony. Or, you could use the `BigInteger` type (but it will need some work to ensure the `BigInteger` never exceeds 96 bits, if you must ensure that).

Comment: @TonyHopkinson - _array[3] has length of 3 not 4.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway. I know , I was referring to the subscript not the dimension in the declaration.

Answer (score 6):

`decimal` is basically a 96-bit integer with a scaling factor. You might have some luck using `decimal`. Other than that... you'll need something like [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx)

Of course, given the name `Flag96`: if you are **just** using it for flags (i.e. bitwise rather than integer handling), then a `ulong` and `uint` side by side should work fine. Just pick the field and offset appropriate to the flag you are after.